# Codeigniter - Link with slash causes repetitive URI

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing, href, codeigniter-url

I have a controller named 'list'. It simply lists users after retrieving them from database. The view has pagination, but it is my own pagination. What I want to do is this:

```
www.example.com/list/<page_num> --> show records belongs to page number given
www.example.com/list --> show first page, i.e. it is equal to '...com/list/1'
```

To do so, I have a route like this:

```
$route['list/(:num)'] = "list/index/$1";
```

The problem arises when I want to assign link to href's at page anchors. For example, when I set link for the second page like href="list/2", that 'list' word adds up to the uri and after some clicks I got something like:

```
www.example.com/list/list/list/3
```

If I use href="2", then link becomes

```
www.example.com/2
```

which is invalid. I can use "/" at the end of controller name, I mean instead of using '...com/list', I can use '...com/list/', however it is not the best solution I suppose since some users want to 'pretify' it deleting the slash at the end. I am enough of using base_url for every link, img, css, etc! Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hello there, well you have your own pagination (I recommend using codigniters one its really simple). But as I assume you are somehow generating page links (/link/2, /link/3...) so why not using `base_url('link/' . $page);` in your anchors?

Comment: Set the href with a forward slash at the beginning `href="/list/2"` otherwise it will be relative to the current page.

Comment: On localhost href="/list/2" creates problem since site is under a folder like 'www/project'. Best thing is using base_url() but there are a lot of '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' in the code and I just want to check if there is a way to get rid of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make code simillar to this one

```
function index() {

    redirect('list/1'); //whatever default or you can try _remap()

}

function list( $page = FALSE ) {

    if ($page === FALSE || !$this->_validPageFunction( $page )) $page = '1';

    //... whatever needs to be done here

}

private function _validPageFunction( $page ) {

    // return FALSE (not-valid) or TRUE (valid)

}
```

*sidenote*: try not bother with routes that much, use `index()` function to redirect to default, routes can be/get messy

*sidenote2*: always use `base_url('');` for links.

Comment: I continue to put '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' at the beginnning of every link, thanks.

Comment: note that `base_url()` takes parameter(s), eg you want to generate path `http://localhost/project/controller/controller_parameter1/`, it is much nicer to write it like `<?=base_url('controller/controller_parameter1')?>` also note php short tags.